# starting and stopping the screensaver

Tags: delphi, screensaver, delphi-2006

Should have been simple I would have thought.  I want to force the PC to go into screen saver mode, and exit it when conditions I am checking in by D2006) app come true.  It doesn't seem to work:

```
    if ScreenSaverExitRequested then
        begin
        SystemParametersInfoResult := SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING, 0, @ScreenSaverIsRunning, 0);
        if ScreenSaverIsRunning then
            begin
            SystemParametersInfoResult := SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETSCREENSAVEACTIVE, UINT(false), nil, SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
            end ;
        end ;
....
    if ScreenSaverEntryRequested then
        begin
        SystemParametersInfoResult := SystemParametersInfo (SPI_SETSCREENSAVEACTIVE, 1, nil, SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE) ;
        end ;
```

SystemParametersInfoResult is returning true in each case.  The calls to SystemParametersInfo don't seem to have any effect.  If I place the PC in SS mode by using the "Preview" button on the Control Panel Display Properties dialog, executing my code does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SPI_SETSCREENSAVEACTIVE does not actually start/stop the screensaver.  It is meant for actual screensavers to call to let the OS know that they are running or exiting.  To start the screensaver, try sending a WM_SYSCOMMAND/SC_SCREENSAVE message to the GetDesktopWindow() window.

Comment: Thanks Remy. To go the other way, is there a corresponding message to kick it out of screensaver mode?  At present I'm using 

`  Keybd_Event(VK_LCONTROL ,   1, 0, 0);
`  Keybd_Event(VK_LCONTROL , 1, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
 
and it seems to work OK.

Comment: Not specifically, no.  You have to either fake user input, like you are already doing, or else you would have to find the screen saver window and then send it a WM_CLOSE message.  See this FAQ: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301462.aspx.